# Inserting into the sorted linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Im getting `nullpointerexception` in this line:

`while(data > current.data)`

I have an ordered list that is sorted in ascending order, i.e. the `insertInPos()` inserts a node in a proper position. But why am I getting `nullpointer`?

```
public void insertInPos(int data){
        if(head == null){
            head = new Node(data, null);
        }
        else if(head.data > data){
            Node newNode = new Node(data, null);
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
        else{
            Node newNode = new Node(data, null);
            Node current = head;
            Node previous = null;
            while(data > current.data){
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            previous.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = current;
        }
    }
```

**main Class**

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
        myList.insertInPos(1);
        myList.insertInPos(2);//Getting nullpointer from here
        myList.insertInPos(3);
        myList.insertInPos(4);
        myList.insertInPos(7);
        myList.insertInPos(7);
        myList.insertInPos(8);
        System.out.println();

        myList.displayList();
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the stack trace

Comment: @UUID, I added the main method, please take a look

Comment: Exception occurs at `while (data > current.data)`, do a pre null check before accessing it

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because `current` become `null` at the end of your list.

Change your condition to following

```
while(current != null && data > current.data){
    previous = current;
    current = current.next;
}
```

Comment: Just copy exactly what I have posted. i.e. `while(current != null && data > current.data)`. `current != null` before `&&`